# Is there an easy way to create a "Movie-name" entity in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I want to create an action that takes the name of a Movie or Tv show and returns some details about it.

The problem is that I need to add all the possible tv show names to an entity.

Even then there is the limit of 3000 for the maximum number of entities in an Entity. Is there a way around this problem?

Ideally I would like to give it some sample tv show names and when the user says a new tv show name(one that the entity doesn't contain), it is able to recognise it and pass it on to the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom entity, and train it with as many examples as you can. Additionally, mark the **allowed automatic expansion**, so that dialogflow will be able to recognize the names which you have not defined.

The problem could still be there, that dialogflow might recognize something as movie name which is not a movie name, for that you should have a validation function in your webhook code. If validation fails, you can prompt the user again for correct movie name.